# Can users besides Administrator run defrag in XP?

Tags: windows-xp, administrator, defragment

I know you can't do this by default, you will get somethign like "You must have administrator privileges to run this application.." or whatever, but I have tried various ways to get around this. I have added the group Users to the 'Perform Volume Maintence' tasks in Local Security Settings, added defrag to the local security settings as non-restricted, and tried changing the file permissions as administrator as well for normal Users to use defrag, none of which worked. Is there any way for a normal user to run defrag on a computer? If I were at home, I would just do this by logging on as administrator, but this is for school. Does anyone have and suggestions, or know how to do this?

Basically I want everything on the user account to remain the same, except add the privlege of running disk defrag, either from the command line or the application.

Comment: Have you tried adding them to Power Users?  It might be a bit much, but I believe it should do the job without giving them full Admin.

Comment: Not yet, I do not think that the teachers would appreciate it if I raised too many of the priveleges

Comment: Since you didn't specify your environment or what restrictions/allowances you have in configuring it, I only suggested what seemed logical.  You might want to add those details to the question.

Comment: That's barely even a side-note, and does nothing to clarify your position in regards to administration of the school computer or its intended users. Is this a general-use "production" system, or is it something more disposable like a lab environment? Are the systems belonging to instructors?  Are the computers or accounts individually assigned, or shared? Who are the users, and what sort of tasks are they generally expected to perform on the system aside from Defrag? Where do you fit in, in all this? All this (and more) must be considered when determining which privileges to assign and how.

Comment: I've given you one possible answer, and you've effectively declined it as not suitable for your environment.  Without further knowledge of your environment, nobody can be sure whether or not their answer will be appropriate or acceptable for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to another users answer, you could use an 'anti-persistent hard drive' utility, which records all changes to a file using a custom HDD driver, and dumps these changes on reboot. This is matter of opinion but I preferred HDGuard to DeepFreeze. It was much better in a large networked environment.

Anyway, as for defragmenting without admin priveleges, you should set up a scheduled task on these machines to begin defragmenting say once a fortnight, with administrative priveleges. This would run in the background, transparent to less priveleged users.

Simply call `defrag.exe` as the task to execute. (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283080).

Answer (score -1):

School lab users should have no need to run a defrag on computers.  If a defrag is needed, setup a sceduled task that runs the defrag at your desired interval (IE nightly, weekly, etc).  Better yet, the machines would be forzen with software like DeepFreeze and be scheduled for regular reboots....never have fragmentation issues afterwards as all changes since last reboot are tossed.